# How to open "Network Connections" window programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-xp, control-panel

How to open "Network Connections" window programmatically using C# in Win7, XP??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Start a new process using shell execute, and run NCPA.cpl.  Like so:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("NCPA.cpl");
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

As an extra reference, wikipedia has a pretty comprehensive list of the applets available to you that you can start in this way: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Control_Panel_applets.

Edit:
As a small addition, it may be more sensible to invoke the required control panel applet using the string "control appletname".  This is because while most applets can be started with their .cpl name alone, some of them, such as the Administrative Tools, don't have a .cpl name, so you need to use "control admintools" instead.

Edit 2:
As an additional reference, check out this knowledge base article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192806.

Comment: +1, a few seconds before I was ready to submit a similar answer :-)

Comment: are there any reference for things can be used after "control" command??

Comment: Try the link I just added, but I'm not sure you're going to find a more comprehensive list than the wikipedia one.

Comment: Is direct opening of properties from the connected network possible?

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

[...]

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("NCPA.cpl");
```

[...]