# Can Win32 applications open the system's settings from code?

Tags: c, winapi

Is it possible to open Windows' settings dialogs using Win32 API calls from C? Such as the monitor settings (the one that allows you to set the monitor's resolution), and the network settings (the one that allows you to set the Wifi settings).

If it is possible, how to do that?

Or, is this not possible at all, and the user has to manually open them?

Comment: [Launch the Windows Settings app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app).

Comment: Most of the control panel can be opened using `Process.Start` (or [`CreateProcessW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) for Win32 applications). See [How to open "Network Connections" window programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032667/how-to-open-network-connections-window-programmatically). The process names you're looking for are likely ["control desk.cpl,,3"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5162437/14956277) and "netcpl.cpl".

Comment: Win32 is the native API and is not necessary to ask "is it possible". If computer is able to do something under Windows, you can do it from Win32.

Comment: @i48 Feel free to read *"is it possible"* as *"is it possible using a supported API"*. And no, the Win32 API is **not** the native API. It's the API of the Win32 subsystem. There are things you can do with the Native API that aren't possible using the Win32 API.

Comment: @IInspectable: Can that Windows settings app be launched from a plain C app too? The link that you posted only shows how to launch it from C# and C++/WinRT.

Comment: I don't know whether you can pass the listed URI's into `ShellExecuteEx`, which would be immediately accessible from C code. If you do have to call `LaunchUriAsync` instead, that'd be problematic. While the API can be called from a desktop application, to my knowledge there are no C projections readily available. You'd have to call that from C++ instead.

Comment: @i486 "*If computer is able to do something under Windows, you can do it from Win32*" - not necessarily. A lot of Windows' internal functionality is behind hidden/restricted APIs that Windows can use internally but user-mode apps can't access.

Comment: I added the [tag:c] tag since that is relevant here. The same question would have a different answer for C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Launch the Windows Settings app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app) explains how to pull up the Windows Settings app using the `ms-settings:` URI scheme. It also lists the supported URIs, including the ones this question is asking for (`ms-settings:network-wifi` and `ms-settings:display`).

While the documentation proposes using the Windows Runtime API [`Launcher.LaunchUriAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync) this is a fair bit complex with C (as opposed to C++). Since the URIs can be invoked from the command prompt using the [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) command (e.g. `start ms-settings:display`), it's reasonable to assume that [`ShellExecuteExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexw) can handle the `ms-settings:` URI scheme as well.

And indeed, this does appear to work:

```c
#include <Windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    SHELLEXECUTEINFOW sei = {
        .cbSize = sizeof(sei),
        .hwnd = NULL,
        .lpVerb = L"open",
        .lpFile = L"ms-settings:display",
        //.lpFile = L"ms-settings:network-wifi",
        .nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL,
    };
    if (!ShellExecuteExW(&sei))
    {
        printf("Failed with error code %d", GetLastError());
    }
}
```

I wasn't able to find any documentation that specifies this behavior, so this may well be an unsupported implementation detail. I will also mention that while [`SHELLEXECUTEINFOW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfow) has an `lpClass` field that can be used to specify a URI protocol scheme, none of my iterations to use it worked for the `ms-settings:` URI scheme.